# How to get IEnumerable Type of Type

Tags: c#, .net

I have factory method that returns `Type` of a POCO given a Key.

```
    public static Type GetType(string key)
    {
        var name = string.format("MyPOCOClass{0},MyAssembly",key);
        return Type.GetType(name);
    }
```

So lets say value of the Key is `One` and assume that the class `MyPOCOClassOne`exists in MyAssembly

in above case i wanted type of `IEnumerable<MyPOCOClassOne>`
How do i do that?

Comment: Change your hardcoded string to match what you're looking for?

Comment: You can use [Type.MakeGenericType()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype(v=vs.110).aspx).

Answer (score 2):

You want to take advantage of `Type.MakeGenericType`([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.makegenerictype%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)). In your case:

```
Type enumerable = typeof(IEnumerable<>); //Unresolved generic!
Type yourType = GetType(someKey); //OP Method

return enumerable.MakeGenericType(yourType);
```